# Display parameters bound to query when fail happens

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink

Using Eclipselink with MySQL. When my entities are not validated properly and invalid data tries to leak into the database, the runtime exception is being thrown with following details:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit
JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception:
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'ip_address' at row 1
Error Code: 1406
Call: INSERT INTO statistics (action_name, created_at, ip_address, object_id, object_type, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
     bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.example.Statistics@3153ead4)"
```

My question is: how to discover and save in logs the values of the bound parameters from the exception? The `6 parameters bound` does not help much.

---

EDIT:

Simple yet powerful solution is to override the `toString()` method of an entity. Then it will be used in logs, revealing details of the object that was about to be saved:

```
...
Call: INSERT INTO statistics (action_name, created_at, ip_address, object_id, object_type, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
  bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Statistics{ID=null, ObjectType=PRODUCT, Action=VIEW, ObjectId=1, User=null, IP=someRandomInvalidTooLongIpAddress})"
```

However, I still wonder if there is any *flag* I can set to expand the `X parameters bound` phrase automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable logging of parameters using the eclipselink.logging.parameters persistence property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging for more info on logging in EclipseLInk.