# EclipseLink JPA re-orders column-names in INSERT statement and causes exceptions

Tags: jpa, insert, eclipselink

I am using the latest version of PostgreSQL and postgresql-9.4.1208.jar (JDBC library).

- using glassfish 4.1
- EclipseLink Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696

Need assistance to FORCE the order of the column-names in the INSERT SQL autogenerated by JPA.

The INSERT SQL (automatically created by entityMgr.persist(...));
Note: the ordering of columns is so wacky, but the values are EXACTLY as I have in the java source (I even prefixed the columns with "order#" to track).

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
ERROR: column "c08_cancel_dt" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type character varying
    Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
    Position: 211
    Error Code: 0
    Call: INSERT INTO apns_new_request (c01_seqnum, c03_app_on_device,
    c08_cancel_dt, c02_device_id, c07_due_dt, c05_item_id,
    c11_item_title, c10_modified, c09_received, c06_request_state,
    c04_event_src)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [11 parameters bound]
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(
    afjkalkhawifualjfklsdjkczsd,        <<-- c02_
    iOS-Calendar-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz,    <<-- c03_
    LaptopBrowser,                      <<-- c04_
    123000123,                          <<-- c05_
    1,2016-05-06T20:51:44.662-04:00,    <<-- c06_
    null,                               <<-- c07_
    2016-05-05T20:51:44.662-04:00,      <<-- c08_
    2016-05-05T20:51:44.662-04:00,      <<-- c09_
    Hi-OffsetDateTime-1!)               <<-- c10_
```

Not an issue, but Notice the same wacky-ordering below, during TABLE-CREATE, how the column-names prefixed to force ordering fails... during deployment (persistence.xml has 'drop-and-create-tables')

```
 org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/iOS_RemoteNotif/WEB-INF/classes/_APNSPersistenceUnit.sql] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1462495579354] [levelValue: 500] [[
    CREATE TABLE apns_new_request (c01_seqnum  BIGINT NOT NULL , c03_app_on_device  CHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
    c08_cancel_dt  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NULL , c02_device_id  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
    c07_due_dt  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL , c05_item_id  CHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
    c11_item_title  VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , c10_modified  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL ,
    c09_received  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL , c06_request_state  SMALLINT NOT NULL ,
    c04_event_src  CHAR(64) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (c01_seqnum))]]
```

Comment: Post some code. While you think the column order is causing you issues the issue is more likely to be in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The InsertObjectQuery is just calling toString on the object it is inserting, and is NOT showing the parameters bound to the statement.  Parameters would be shown within the "[11 parameters bound]" of the log, if you have enabled parameter [binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453302/display-parameters-bound-to-query-when-fail-happens)

Show the mapping for the c08_cancel_dt field to see why it might be having issues, as well as the parameters being used for it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink Bug (when influenced by custom @annotations - which causes column positioning mismatch for auto-generated INSERT SQL)

Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696

Very simple proof.

I replaced all `java.time.OffsetDateTime` with `java.util.Date` - for all date fields in the Entity Bean.
I got rid of my @CustomBeanValidator annotations from that bean.

Then I deleted (*my own*) Custom Bean-Validator java files (`MyOffsetDateTimeValidator` & `OffsetDateTimeValidator`),
as well as the Custom JPA-field-converter java class (`JPAOffsetDateConverter`).

See [My other post that contains the code for these two java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939054/hv000030-no-validator-could-be-found-for-type-java-time-offsetdatetime)

`mvn clean package deploy` ....

Now JPA Works like a charm - no errors and no warnings in the GlassFish logs.
Data is stored perfectly in appropriate columns in the PostgreSQL tables!

P.S: Unfortunately, I still do not have timezone data in the database, so will have to use workarounds/ additional entity-bean fields...

Comment: Switching from java.time.OffsetDateTime with java.util.Date and it working might indicate a problem with the OffsetDateTime, not your non-jpa annotations.  My guess is that it is serializing the OffsetDateTime object to the driver, and since it is not a sql.Date, Time or Timestamp, it isn't understood causing the error.